# Why does qsort() not have a return value?

Tags: c

I'm a C++ programmer for the most part, but just for fun I was trying to do some generic programming in C. In particular, I implemented a generic sorting algorithm. The signature of my function is

```
int sort(void   *data,
         size_t num_elems,
         size_t elem_size,
         int    (*cmp)(const void*, const void*))
```

When I compared this to `qsort()` in the standard library, I noticed that unlike my function, `qsort()` does not have a return value. Since sorting an array will always require swapping elements, the implementation requires a temporary storage of size `elem_size`. As C doesn't have templates, `elem_size` is not known at compile time, so the temporary storage must be allocated dynamically, which could fail. In that case, `qsort()` couldn't sort the array, but it couldn't report the error either, so there is no way of knowing if the array is sorted upon return.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that? How can I change the order of the elements without additional storage for at least one element?

Comment: Ignore that, I’m stupid and thought you wrote `num_elems` instead of `elem_size`. It’s still possible to exchange arbitrary amounts of memory without a variable amount of temporary storage, though; just do it in fixed-size units (e.g. one byte at a time).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any partitioning algorithm needs to be able to swap two elements, and the `qsort` API means that the code doesn't know how big they are at compile-time. But they don't need to be swapped as a whole; they can be swapped one byte at a time. (That's effectively what memcpy would do anyway.)

The following comment and macro are right at the beginning of `qsort.c` in the Gnu libc implementation. (Note that the code is subject to the LGPL)

```
/* Byte-wise swap two items of size SIZE. */
#define SWAP(a, b, size)                                                      \
  do                                                                          \
    {                                                                         \
      size_t __size = (size);                                                 \
      char *__a = (a), *__b = (b);                                            \
      do                                                                      \
        {                                                                     \
          char __tmp = *__a;                                                  \
          *__a++ = *__b;                                                      \
          *__b++ = __tmp;                                                     \
        } while (--__size > 0);                                               \
    } while (0)
```

Comment: Thanks, that indeed solves the problem. I wonder why I didn't think of that myself.

Comment: @cthl: Everything is obvious... after you've seen it. All of us have kicked ourselves many times for not seeing it first.

Answer (score 3):

The function cannot fail -- well, unless the arguments are invalid in which case it's undefined behaviour and the function could not reliably detect that anyway.

`qsort` doesn't allocate any memory per se. (Of course it could do anything, but it's not allowed to fail due to memory allocation failure, so the implementor has to take that into account).

Comment: But how is it even possible to implement a sorting algorithm *without* memory allocation? Any implementation needs to change the order of the elements, and thus needs a place to store at least one element temporarily.

Comment: @cthl: It could swap one byte at a time

Comment: It could use the CPU registers for example. Or it could do the XOR trick .

Comment: @cthl I'd expect a `qsort()` to use a small fixed size buffer, say 16 and swap through that, rather than 1 byte at a time - using that buffer in a loop if needed.

Comment: @chux: the Gnu implementation uses the macro I quote my answer, so it really is a byte at a time. The FreeBSD version uses `long` or  `int` if the size and the address of the vector are multiples of  the size of the hose respective types. That would be UB on a system with trap representations for integer types; if you wanted to avoid the UB you would have to use memcpy at which point you might as well use the byte at a time version.

Comment: Note that you can even do cycles this way, not just swaps. https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/stdlib/qsort.c